# Compiling Amensia The Dark Descent open source code in Visual Studio 2019 gives error regarding xutility.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

https://github.com/FrictionalGames/AmnesiaTheDarkDescent

So Frictional Games released the open source for Amnesia The Dark Descent. They also included a visual studio solution. So I download and open up. The compilation goes good except an error where a certain source file cannot compile due to an illegal expression. The error message goes:

*1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xutility(1544,5): error C2056: illegal expression (compiling source file sources\gui\GuiSet.cpp)*

*1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xutility(1544,39): error C2056: illegal expression (compiling source file sources\gui\GuiSet.cpp)*

Now, I haven't touched any of the code so the error is most likely an issue with the release in relation to my current Visual Studio version. Is there a way for me to resolve this. If you want to help please download the source code and try yourself.

Comment: Why not tell us the full error message?  What expression is illegal?

Comment: _"If you want to help please download the source code and try yourself"_ That's not how Stackoverflow works. If you want help post a [mcve]. Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2056?view=vs-2019? C2056 is an undeclared identifier

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could show me the snippet of the problem code. Because it will be helpful to solve the problem. Also, you could try to use VS2010 to detect whether this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I just randomly tried to do the same as well, I can tell you this specific problem is because the definition of cGuiRenderObjectCompare::operator() is missing the const keyword. You need to fix `bool operator()(const cGuiRenderObject& aObjectA, const cGuiRenderObject& aObjectB);` into `bool operator()(const cGuiRenderObject& aObjectA, const cGuiRenderObject& aObjectB) const;`

You need a similar fix in both GuiSet.h and GuiSet.cpp.